# Find file in folder without knowing the extension?

Tags: python, file, search, directory, match

Let's say I want to search for a file name "myfile" in a folder named "myfolder", how can I do it without knowing the format of the file?
Another question: how to list all files of a folder *and* all the files of it's subfolders (and so on)?
Thank you.

Comment: If you're happy with a answer, please accept it. Otherwise you can adding more information to your question. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
import os
import glob
 
path = 'myfolder/'
for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, 'myfile.*') ):
    print "current file is: " + infile
```

if you want to list all the files in the folder, simply change the for loop into

```
for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path) ):
```

Answer (score 4):

To list all files in a folder and its subfolders and so on, use the [`os.walk` function](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk):

```py
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/blah/myfolder'):
    for name in files:
        if 'myfile' in name:
            print (f"Found {name}")
```

In the easier case where you just want to look in `'myfolder'` and not its subfolders, just use the [`os.listdir` function](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir):

```py
import os
for name in os.listdir('/blah/myfolder'):
    if 'myfile' in name:
        print (f"Found {name}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

Loop through each file in the directory, get the names as strings and check to see if they begin with `myfile` by splitting the string on the `.` you can compare what you are looking for with what you have.

Answer (score 0):

The `format` (by which I mean you assume file type) is not related to its extension (which is part of its name).

If you're on a UNIX, you can use the [find](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/findcmd.htm) command. `find myfolder -name myfile` should work.

If you want a complete listing, you can either use find without any arguments, use `ls` with the `-R` option or use the `tree` command. All of these are on UNIX.

Comment: It was supposed to be python code, I think. But you can always use the [`subprocess.check_output` function](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), right? :)

Comment: Yes. I didn't notice the tag. The question itself seemed very "shellish".

Answer (score 0):

Also you can have a look to os.walk function if you want to look inside subdirectories.

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk